# How can I add to my table filter to allow for multiple checkbox selections, as well as filtering from a dropdown?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, filter, html-table

I've got a table that can be filtered by multiple checkboxes, as well as by a "select" dropdown.  Essentially, what I want to be able to do is click on multiple checkboxes in order to find each row containing that class, so class 1 and 3, or example, and then filter it by the location.

I've gotten really close at this point, where I can select both the location (which is also a class, two letters for state abbreviations), and a single class from the checkboxes, but I want people to be able to compare multiple classes from the checkboxes.

The problem is something I understand, but can't seem to figure out how to fix. The code adds each class to the end of the "tr". This means if you apply 2 filters from the checkboxes, it finds nothing, instead of finding everything from each filter.  While this behavior is perfectly functional for 1 checkbox and the Dropdown, meaning it will only give me Filter 1 values from Tennessee, I want it to be able to give me Filter 2, Filter 3, and Filter 4 at the same time, if I so choose.

Any ideas on how to alter this to make it allow multiple checkbox selections?

By the way, I'm very limited in what JavaScript/jQuery plugins I can use, which is why I'm fighting so hard to use tableSorter with this solution.

My HTML:

```
 <form name="FilterForm" id="FilterForm" action="" method="">
    <input type="checkbox" name="filterStatus" value="1" /><label for="filter_1">Filter 1</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="filterStatus" value="2" /><label for="filter_2">Filter 2</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="filterStatus" value="3" /><label for="filter_3">Filter 3</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="filterStatus" value="4" /><label for="filter_4">Filter 4</label>
    <select type="dropdown" name="filterStatus" id="chooseState" class="filter">
      <option value="ZZ">--Choose State--</option>
      <option value="TN">Tennessee</option>
      <option value="MO">Missouri</option>
      <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
      <option value="IA">Iowa</option>
    </select><label>State</label>
       </form>

<table id="StatusTable">
     <tbody>                        
       <tr class="1 TN">
       <td class="Name"></td>
       <td class="ID"></td>
       <td class="Type"></td>
       <td class="Location">City, Tennessee</td>
       <td class="Class"></td>
       <td class="Received"></td>
       <td class="Action"></td>
       <td class="Status">Active</td>
     </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

JavaScript:

```
    $("input[name='filterStatus'], select.filter").change(function () {
var classes = "";
var stateClass = ""

    $("input[name='filterStatus']").each(function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    classes += "." + $(this).val();
    }
});

$("select.filter").each(function() {
if ($(this).val() != 'ZZ') {
stateClass += "." + $(this).val();
}
});

if (classes == "" && stateClass == "") {
// if no filters selected, show all items
$("#StatusTable tbody tr").show();
} else {
// otherwise, hide everything...
$("#StatusTable tbody tr").hide();

    // then show only the matching items
rows = $("#StatusTable tr" + classes + stateClass);
if (rows.size() > 0) {
rows.show();
}
}

});
```

Comment: You said the problem was with the checkbox, but i can't see where you use checkbox in your code, can you reproduce it in a fiddle ? http://jsfiddle.net/ZRRnG/

Comment: I managed to break it during my last attempt to edit. I've edited my question to reinclude it.  Let me see if I can get it in a fiddle.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you know the problem, ill skip the explication and jump to the solution.

Use the `.filter()` method mixed with an array.

Instead of expending a string, push the class name into an array :

```
var classes = [];

$("input[name='filterStatus']").each(function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        classes.push('.'+$(this).val());
    }
});
```

Then when selecting the row, use `.filter()` just like that :

```
rows = $("#StatusTable tr" + stateClass).filter(classes.length ? classes.join(',') : '*')
```

Then everything work fine!

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZRRnG/4/)**

Comment: I'm reviewing it now.  Thanks for your suggestions, I'll let you know how it goes!

Comment: IT LIVES!  Thank you very much for your time, as it has saved me from beating my head against the wall further.  Enjoy the rest of your day, and your "Answer!" status.

Comment: I've stumbled across a problem with the answer.  If you select only a state, it gives nothing.  Any thoughts on how to get around that?  I'm working on it on my end as well.