# How can I achieve filter options in php like redbus.in ?

Tags: php, arrays, json

How do I implement filter option like redbus.in.
My projects is on PHP.
Please refer below link for example : 
http://www.redbus.in/Booking/SelectBus.aspx?fromCityId=462_2&toCityId=210&doj=04-Apr-2015&busType=Any&opId=0

Comment: This is much too broad of a question with no basis to indicate where you are stuck on the problem.  To get a solution like that would likely require a solid understanding of how to form proper SQL queries, javascript, AJAX methodologies, jQuery or similar DOM manipulation, etc.

Answer (score -2):

For the sorting: Try using [DataTables](https://www.datatables.net/) Plugin for jQuery

For the filter: This thread should help you: [How can I add to my table filter to allow for multiple checkbox selections, as well as filtering from a dropdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17622103/how-can-i-add-to-my-table-filter-to-allow-for-multiple-checkbox-selections-as-w)

Comment: There are so many filters options in redbus like Operator Name, Bus Type, Boarding Points ets.., I want to achieve that checklist functionality.

Comment: Sorry than i missunderstood, i thought you want the sorting like that.

So in that case, maybe this thread is usefull to you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17622103/how-can-i-add-to-my-table-filter-to-allow-for-multiple-checkbox-selections-as-w