# Filter table with checkboxes

Tags: jquery, checkbox, html-table

I am filtering a table with checkboxes.
The code I have works fine, in some aspects.

I want it to filter results if they meet all the checks, not one.

based on: [How can I add to my table filter to allow for multiple checkbox selections, as well as filtering from a dropdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17622103/how-can-i-add-to-my-table-filter-to-allow-for-multiple-checkbox-selections-as-w)

My [Example](http://lorencook.com/example/table.html)

```js
$("input[name='filterStatus'], select.filter").change(function() {
  var classes = [];
  var stateClass = ""

  $("input[name='filterStatus']").each(function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      classes.push('.' + $(this).val());
    }
  });

  if (classes == "" && stateClass == "") {
    // if no filters selected, show all items
    $("#StatusTable tbody tr").show();
  } else {
    // otherwise, hide everything...
    $("#StatusTable tbody tr").hide();

    // then show only the matching items
    rows = $("#StatusTable tr" + stateClass).filter(classes.length ? classes.join(',') : '*');
    if (rows.size() > 0) {
      rows.show();
    }
  }

});
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <form name="FilterForm" id="FilterForm" action="" method="">
    <input type="checkbox" name="filterStatus" value="ISO " />
    <label for="filter_1">ISO</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="filterStatus" value="AMCA" />
    <label for="filter_2">AMCA</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="filterStatus" value="UL" />
    <label for="filter_3">UL</label>
  </form>

  <table border="1" id="StatusTable">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>ISO</th>
        <th>AMCA</th>
        <th>UL</th>
      </tr>
      <tbody>
        <tr class="ISO">
          <td class="Name">Name1</td>
          <td class="ISO">&#x2713;</td>
          <td class="AMCA">&nbsp;</td>
          <td class="UL">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="ISO AMCA">
          <td class="Name">Name2</td>
          <td class="ISO">&#x2713;</td>
          <td class="AMCA">&#x2713;</td>
          <td class="UL">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="ISO AMCA UL">
          <td class="Name">Name3</td>
          <td class="ISO">&#x2713;</td>
          <td class="AMCA">&#x2713;</td>
          <td class="UL">&#x2713;</td>
        </tr>

      </tbody>
  </table>
  <script></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: If you created a Fiddle or posted the code to your example with your question it would make it easier for others to help you.

Comment: Will the row always contain the correct class list of its cells?

Comment: Yes I can assign the row with the class

Comment: Please dont forget to mark the answer you like as the correct one.

Comment: thanks I will after I look at them

Comment: I like both answers.

Comment: @erkaner: [link](http://lorencook.com/example/table-1.html )

<br/>
I changed it to not show the table at first
They work
Thanks!

Comment: @McWayWeb: [link](http://lorencook.com/example/table-2.html )  <br/>
I changed it to not show the table at first
They work
Thanks!

Comment: I have an issue with both:

If I pick a choice that is not found on the table, the header is shown

See demo

Comment: I got it working:
http://lorencook.com/example/table-2a.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Modify your jQuery where it loops through each row. Create a tag variable to store whether or not the row is to be shown, and set it to **true** by default.

Now when you loop through each row, you will also loop through each class you are checking for. If at any point, a loop test fails, set your show variable to **false** to keep the row hidden.

```js
$("input[name='filterStatus']").change(function () {
    var classes = [];

    $("input[name='filterStatus']").each(function () {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) { classes.push('.' + $(this).val()); }
    });

    if (classes == "") { // if no filters selected, show all items
        $("#StatusTable tbody tr").show();
    } else { // otherwise, hide everything...
        $("#StatusTable tbody tr").hide();

        $("#StatusTable tr").each(function () {
            var show = true;
            var row = $(this);
            classes.forEach(function (className) {
                if (row.find('td' + className).html() == '&nbsp;') { show = false; }
            });
            if (show) { row.show(); }
        });
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
    
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <form name="FilterForm" id="FilterForm" action="" method="">
            <input type="checkbox" name="filterStatus" value="ISO " />
            <label for="filter_1">ISO</label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="filterStatus" value="AMCA" />
            <label for="filter_2">AMCA</label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="filterStatus" value="UL" />
            <label for="filter_3">UL</label>
        </form>
        <table border="1" id="StatusTable">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>ISO</th>
                    <th>AMCA</th>
                    <th>UL</th>
                </tr>
                <tbody>
                    <tr class="ISO">
                        <td class="Name">Name1</td>
                        <td class="ISO">&#x2713;</td>
                        <td class="AMCA">&nbsp;</td>
                        <td class="UL">&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="ISO AMCA">
                        <td class="Name">Name2</td>
                        <td class="ISO">&#x2713;</td>
                        <td class="AMCA">&#x2713;</td>
                        <td class="UL">&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="ISO AMCA UL">
                        <td class="Name">Name3</td>
                        <td class="ISO">&#x2713;</td>
                        <td class="AMCA">&#x2713;</td>
                        <td class="UL">&#x2713;</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
        </table>
        <script></script>
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 5):

Here with the help of this below code. You can filter the table based on checkbox checked and when you didn't select any checkbox then it will display all the records.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".name").on("click", function() {
  name_list = []
  $("#myTable tr").hide()
  var flag = 1
  $("input:checkbox[name=name]:checked").each(function(){
    flag = 0;
     var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
       $("#myTable tr").filter(function() {
            if($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
          $(this).show()
     });
   });
    if(flag == 1)
     $("#myTable tr").show()
  });
});
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}
td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

</script>
<style>
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Filterable Table</h2>

<input type="checkbox" class="name" name="name" value="John" />John
<input type="checkbox" class="name" name="name" value="July" />July
<br><br>

<table>
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Email</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>john@example.com</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Mary</td>
    <td>Moe</td>
    <td>mary@mail.com</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>July</td>
    <td>Dooley</td>
    <td>july@greatstuff.com</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>July</td>
    <td>Dooley</td>
    <td>july@greatstuff.com</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Anja</td>
    <td>Ravendale</td>
    <td>a_r@test.com</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
  
<p>Note that we start the search in tbody, to prevent filtering the table headers.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Nice solution. I feel we get the same effect with `.toggle()` function as well (for capturing checkbox _checked_ and _unchecked_ states).

Answer (score 3):

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/erkaner/u12te5jb/

Here is my solution

```
$("input[name='filterStatus']").change(function () {

var count1 = $("input[name='filterStatus']:checked").length;//number of checked items

$("#StatusTable>tbody> tr").each(function () {//for each row
    var count2 = 0;//this is the count of td that has ✓ 
    var row = $(this);//the current row
    $("input[name='filterStatus']:checked").each(function () {//for each checked item
        var inputVal = $(this).val();//get the value, which is class of the corresponding td, see below
        if (row.find('.' + inputVal).html().indexOf("✓") >= 0)//if the td that corresponds to the selected checkbox contains ✓
            count2++;//then increase
    });

    if (count1 == count2) //if counts match
        row.show();//then show
    else 
        row.hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: I can use it in fiddle.

http://lorencook.com/example/table-1.html

But my demo is bad

Comment: can you move `<script></script>` part to the head section not in the body?

Answer (score 1):

[jQuery Scrollable, Sortable, Filterable table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192608/jquery-scrollable-sortable-filterable-table) references [DataTables](https://datatables.net) library which under https://datatables.net/news/ has an entry for 8th Feb 2019:

> Yevgen Gorbunkov has written a very nice plug-in for DataTables which
>   shows a drop down filtering from the header allowing union searches to
>   be performed. The source is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/ygorbunkov/datatables-multiple-criteria-filter).

I've converted the example from https://jsfiddle.net/ahqso1j5/ to the snippet here:

```js
// Plug-in source available at:
// https://github.com/ygorbunkov/datatables-multiple-criteria-filter
$(document).ready(function () {
//Source data definition 
var tableData = [{
  name: 'Clark Kent',
  city: 'Metropolis',
  race: 'cryptonian'
 }, {
  name: 'Bruce Wayne',
  city: 'Gotham',
  race: 'human'
 }, {
  name: 'Steve Rogers',
  city: 'New York',
  race: 'superhuman'
 }, {
  name: 'Peter Parker',
  city: 'New York',
  race: 'superhuman'
 }, {
  name: 'Thor Odinson',
  city: 'Asgard',
  race: 'god'
 }, {
  name: 'Jonathan Osterman',
  city: 'New York',
  race: 'superhuman'
 }, {
  name: 'Walter Kovacs',
  city: 'New Jersey',
  race: 'human'
 }, {
  name: 'Arthur Curry',
  city: 'Atlantis',
  race: 'superhuman'
 }, {
  name: 'Tony Stark',
  city: 'New York',
  race: 'human'
 }, {
  name: 'Scott Lang',
  city: 'Coral Gables',
  race: 'human'
 }, {
  name: 'Bruce Banner',
  city: 'New York',
  race: 'superhuman'
 }
];
//DataTable definition 
window.dataTable = $('#mytable').DataTable({
  sDom: 'tF',
  data: tableData,
  columns: [{
    data: 'name',
    title: 'Name'
   }, {
    data: 'city',
    title: 'City'
   }, {
    data: 'race',
    title: 'Race'
  }]
});
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/ygorbunkov/datatables-multiple-criteria-filter@master/js/mFilter.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/ygorbunkov/datatables-multiple-criteria-filter@master/css/mFilter.css">
</head>
<body>
  <table id="mytable"></table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am doing this, the code will show the selected checkbox rows,

```js
 $('#btnReconcile').click(function () {
            $("#tblReconcilReportDetails>tbody> tr").each(function () {
                var row = $(this);
                var isChecked = $(this).find('td').eq(0).find('input[type="checkbox"].chkReconcil').is(':checked');
                if (isChecked) {
                    row.show();
                } else {
                    row.hide();
                }
            });
        });
```